# Making image responsive using media query

Tags: html, css

Can Anyone help making this list layout responsive for different screen-size, using media query? Currently, it is a fluid layout that is adjusting as per screen size. I need suggestion on using media query with it.

My original code is at https://jsfiddle.net/7qsp1k0o/2/

```css
.item.list-group-item {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.item.list-group-item .list-group-image {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.item.list-group-item .thumbnail {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.item.list-group-item .caption {
  padding: 9px 9px 0px 9px;
}
.item.list-group-item:before,
.item.list-group-item:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.item.list-group-item img {
  float: left;
}
.item.list-group-item:after {
  clear: both;
}
.list-group-item-text {
  margin: 0 0 11px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div id="products" class="row list-group ">
    <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4 list-group-item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400X250/000/fff" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Activity title</h4>
          <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
            Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <p class="lead">
                Charge : $21.000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Apply Now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4 list-group-item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400X250/000/fff" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Activity title</h4>
          <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
            Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <p class="lead">
                Charge : $21.000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Apply Now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item  col-xs-4 col-lg-4 list-group-item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="group list-group-image" src="http://placehold.it/400X250/000/fff" alt="" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        Activity title</h4>
          <p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
            Product description... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <p class="lead">
                Charge : $21.000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Apply Now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Added desired result.
I want that text should not flow below the image, Rather the whole thing (image and box) should scale down to fit the screen size.

Comment: why do use media query, since it is already responsive with bootstrap?

Comment: It is responsive, but I want it to adjust it's style a bit, as per screen size. So that it looks good.

Comment: It works fine. What is your expected result?

Comment: Added desired expectation in edit.

Answer (score 0):

Styling is based on the creativity, however this might help you..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- BEGIN PRODUCTS -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <span class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400" alt="...">
                <h4>Product Tittle</h4>
                <div class="ratings">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                <hr class="line">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <p class="price">$29,90</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-success right" > BUY ITEM</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <span class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400" alt="...">
                <h4>Product Tittle</h4>
                <div class="ratings">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                <hr class="line">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <p class="price">$29,90</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-success right" > BUY ITEM</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <span class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400" alt="...">
                <h4>Product Tittle</h4>
                <div class="ratings">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                <hr class="line">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <p class="price">$29,90</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-success right" > BUY ITEM</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <span class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/500x400" alt="...">
                <h4>Product Tittle</h4>
                <div class="ratings">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                <hr class="line">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <p class="price">$29,90</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-success right" > BUY ITEM</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <!-- END PRODUCTS -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css code

```
h4{
    font-weight: 600;
}
p{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.price{
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #333;
}
.right{
    float:right;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #4B8E4B;
}
.thumbnail{
    opacity:0.70;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; 
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.thumbnail:hover{
    opacity:1.00;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #4bc6ff;
}
.line{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
    .right{
        float:left;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: You see now when we resize screen. All the boxes are becoming. thin like stick :-). They should be adjusted like for small size only one box in a view. For medium screen size 2 boxes in a view.

Comment: Not an issue, I think I can try understand how to use media query.

Comment: @user2816085 for that you need to use different bootstrap class like col-xs-12. See the edit.